# IONIC Local Notification is shown in simulator but not on the device for IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic2

Hi i m developing apps using ionic , there is local notification function for my apps . It works well in simulator but not in real physical device . is there any solution or workaround ?

Comment: What is that you have tried and what did not work. Please share some code.

Comment: add code snapshot